# Referring Values In a matrix

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a function that takes a numeric vector, and for each number checks if the number is the same upside down, returning logical True False.

By upside down I mean, for example if you take 96, the upside down number is 96, and is true.

So far I have created a matrix with the values 0:9 and the corresponding values of the 'fipped ' numbers, 0,1,6,9, and the others being NA.

```
numbers = (0:9)
upside_down_numbers = c(0,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,9,NA,8,6)
ref_table = rbind(numbers,upside_down_numbers)
```

And using a for loop, I can split each input number into it's digits

```
input = c(241234,432,123)

for (number in input){
digits = as.integer(substring(number, seq(nchar(number)), seq(nchar(number))))
print(digits)
}
```

My issue now is comparing each digit to the matrix to get the expected upside down number, because once I get that, I can collapse then reverse the new number and compare to the input number, and get a logical result.

So any help in looking up a value in a matrix, or if there is another method that would allow me to achieve the purpose of the function would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your lookups are simply from 0 to 9, all you need do is add one and index into `upside_down_numbers`:

```
> upside_down_numbers[6+1]
[1] 9
> upside_down_numbers[1+1]
[1] 1
```

Isn't upside-down 2 a 2 and upside-down 5 a 5?

Oh and you can use `strsplit` for easier string splitting:

```
> as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(6973),"")[[1]])
[1] 6 9 7 3
```

Here's a one-liner that returns an upside-downed number or NA if number contains a non-upsidedownable digit:

```
> udnum = function(n){
   as.numeric(paste0(
        upside_down_numbers[
          1+rev(as.numeric(strsplit(as.character(n),"")[[1]]))
          ],collapse=""))}


> udnum(2669)
[1] 6992
> udnum(5526)
[1] 9255
> udnum(4)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In udnum(4) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I've used my modified inversion table with 2 and 5 in it. That's what my calculator looked like!

Comment: You have no idea how much joy it fills me with to see that working, I have spent all day trying to figure this out using an array of google docs and %in% and match combinations.

Comment: It took me about ten minutes. Plus twenty years of experience. Now tick the little tick up there and mark this thing as answered!